# Latitude of Earth reference ellipsoid

Tags: latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry, ellipsoid

I am trying to create a graphic demonstrating the difference between an idealized perfect sphere and the Earth's reference ellipsoid. (I know this is also an approximation, but nevertheless.) To this end I want to also exaggerate the eccentricity of the ellipsoid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

Anyway, should I simply scale a sphere vertically such that the vertical axis is shorter than the horizontal axis? If I have a map of the Earth wrapped around the sphere, is squashing the sphere vertically sufficient? Or do I need to convert between geocentric and geodetic latitude first?

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: See also https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-precise-shape-of-the-Earth-Is-it-a-sphere-spheroid-or-something-else-1/answer/Pathan-Salman

Comment: If your purpose is simply to create visuals to demonstrate the shape of the Earth I wouldn't worry too much about all this; just scale you Earth and its texture vertically and the result should be good for your needs I believe.

Comment: Well, I am trying to demonstrate geodetic latitude. I have already created a texture for the graticule based on geodetic latitude. I now need to know what I should do with the texture lying underneath the graticule, of the continents, oceans, etc. I could simply squash it vertically, as I have described. Or I could UV map it using a method intended for spheres, but not ellipsoids. Or I could... do something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oblate ellipsoids and latitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290239/oblate-ellipsoids-and-latitude)